# R `dplyr` code : `iris %>% dim(.)[1]` meaning?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline

I've made mistake, with interesting output, correct code is :

```
iris %>% dim(.)%>% .[1]
```

incorrect is :

```
iris %>% dim(.)[1]
```

which gives :

```
[1] 5.9 5.0
```

what going on in `iris %>% dim(.)[1]` ?

Comment: It  gives the 5th and 150th observation of the first column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of the expression is to use the dimensions returned from `dim` to subset entries in the first column of the dataframe:

```
> dim(iris)
[1] 150   5
> iris[,1][c(150, 5)]
[1] 5.9 5.0
```

If you leave out the "1" in the index, you can see that rows 150 and 5 are returned:

```
> iris %>% dim(.)[]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
```

This behavior is because [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) allows the dot to be used to retrieve properties of the dataset, and pass them in as arguments to the functions which are being called.

In the magrittr docs:

```
help("%>%", magrittr)
```

> **Using the dot for secondary purposes**
>        Often, some attribute or property of ‘lhs’ is desired in the ‘rhs’
>        call in addition to the value of ‘lhs’ itself, e.g. the number of
>        rows or columns. It is perfectly valid to use the dot placeholder
>        several times in the ‘rhs’ call, but by design the behavior is
>        slightly different when using it inside nested function calls. In
>        particular, if the placeholder is only used in a nested function
>        call, ‘lhs’ will also be placed as the first argument! The reason
>        for this is that in most use-cases this produces the most readable
>        code. For example, ‘iris %>% subset(1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)’ is
>        equivalent to ‘iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)’ but
>        slightly more compact.

So in this case, the subset "function" (`[]`) is being called with the output from `iris %>% dim`.